# How to in view pass array data to controller with model(in one atribute) Yii

Tags: php, yii, model

It is my view in Yii framework.  i wanna pass from here array data to controller with only one model attribute or just array without model. how to do it?

```
<?php $i = 1; foreach ($images as $image):
CHtml::activeLabel($model, 'remove', array('for'=>'rm_'.$image))
CHtml::activeCheckBox($model,'remove',array('name'=>'Obyavlenie[remove]',  'id'=>'rm_'.$image)) // remove is array(attribute) to pass
CHtml::link($image, 'name', array()),$image);
```

in model

```
class Obyavlenie extends CActiveRecord
{
public $remove;// should get array from view
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is this all you've tried?

Comment: just pass array data to controller to  remove some images in folder

Comment: Check what is going in the post request ( is this remove parameter being passed there ? )

Comment: Thanks for help. i got it

Comment: <?php echo CHtml::activeCheckBox($model,'remove',array('name'=>'Obyavlenie[remove]['.$image.']', 'id'=>'rm_'.$image)) ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <?php echo CHtml::activeCheckBox($model,'remove',array('name'=>'Obyavlenie[remove]['.$image‌​.']', 'id'=>'rm_'.$image)) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CheckBoxList`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeCheckBoxList-detail) for multiple values.

In view:

```
// 1. Set data list
$list = array();
foreach ($images as $image):
  $list[ $image ] = CHtml::link($image,'#'); // Change [ $image ] unique identificator to determine image you need
endforeach;

// 2. Output checkboxes
CHtml::activeCheckBoxList($model,'remove',$list,array(
  'template' => '{input} {label}'
));
```

In action:

```
$model = new Obyavlenie('removeImages');
if ( isset( $_POST['Obyavlenie'] ) ) {
   $model->attributes = $_POST['Obyavlenie']
}
```

In model:

```
class Obyavlenie extends CActiveRecord {
  public $remove;

  public function rules(){
    return array(
      // ...
      array( 'remove', 'type', 'type' => 'array', 'on' => 'removeImages' )
    );
  }

  // other model's methods
```

P.S. Obyavlenie -> Advert

Comment: Thanks for advert))      CHtml::activeCheckBoxList($model,'remove',$list,array(
  'template' => '{input} {label}'
)); template for what how to use it.

Comment: i've given you link to documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeCheckBoxList-detail Read it first please.